# Download EC2 instance contents with only aws login info and no pem key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've been given access to an aws account and asked to extract all the data stored on it so that it can be deleted. My issue is that I don't have a pem key because I didn't create the instance, the only thing I have is the email and password of the aws account itself.

I know there is data stored on an ec2 instance and on s3

I've tried logging in using the browser-based ssh that is an option when you select connect for an instance, but I get the error `There was a problem setting up the instance connection` and a retry button but retrying does nothing

I don't have access to the pem key because I didn't set up the instance, and the person that set up the instance can't send it to me because I don't have their contact info

Everything I try to connect doesn't work because I'm missing the Pem key.

Any ideas? or any ideas how to pull the data from a server (that wasn't set up with version control so i can't do that either) without being able to ssh into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is stored on an EBS volume you can detach it from the existing instance and attach it to a new instance, for which you have the key. Otherwise I don't think you are going to be able to get it.

I'm a little confused by "the person that set up the instance can't add me to it." A PEM isn't something you have to be added to. If you have it you can use it. Is there a reason that person can't share it with you?

Comment: Check if the person has by any chance created a password based user use that in case he hasn't the above option is the only way you can login. For attaching and de-attaching you need to create a server is the same az.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant the creator of the instance can't send the pem to me because I don't have their contact info to ask for it

Comment: I don't think the content is on an EBS volume, but I'll check. Is it possible that I can duplicate the whole instance including the data and get access to the duplicated instance?

Comment: I'm 99% confident that if you take a snapshot of an EC2 instance the new instance will need the same key. There is a reason they warn you not to lose it.

Comment: Dangit ok thanks so much I'll dig around to see if I can somehow get a hold of the original creator of the instance